# Eclipse RCP: how to create a popup menu for the selection in a text editor?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Using the Eclipse template I generated this sample which works fine when I select a file in the project explorer. However I want to also make it available when I do right-click on a Text Editor or even when I have some text selected.

What is the right **objectClass** to use in the **objectContribution**?

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
  <objectContribution
                      id="com.example.popup-cli.contribution1"
                      objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
    <menu
          id="com.example.popup.menu1"
          label="New Submenu"
          path="additions">
      <separator
                 name="group1">
      </separator>
    </menu>
    <action
            class="com.example.popup.actions.NewAction"
            enablesFor="1"
            id="com.example.popup.newAction"
            label="New Action"
            menubarPath="com.example.popup.menu1/group1">
    </action>
  </objectContribution>
</extension>
```

Comment: 'org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus' is deprecated, 'org.eclipse.ui.menus' should be used for new code.

Comment: @greg-449 ok, I'll switch to 'org.eclipse.ui.menus' instead. I just don't understand, if it's deprecated why is it available in the template list from the Eclipse Luna SDK? Anyway, I suppose I must use the adapt tag to define in which selection the context menu should be available, but what is the object type to be used for the Text Editor selection?

Comment: 'org.eclipse.ui.menus' works in a different way and doesn't use object types. Instead you go by menu ids - see the help.

Comment: @greg-449 according to the documentation, it also uses a similar approach with the tag <visibleWhen> and <adapt type="" />. But I can't figure out which type should I use to enable the context menu for a selection in a Text Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point you can use the `activeEditorInput` variable to test the current editor input (the file being edited).

For example:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
     locationURI="popup:#AbstractTextEditorRulerContext?after=QuickDiff.Toggle">
     <command
        commandId="org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui.showAnnotation"
        label="%ShowAnnotationAction.label"
        style="push">
        <visibleWhen
           checkEnabled="false">
           <with variable="activeEditorInput">
              <test
                 property="org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.isManaged"
                 value="true">
              </test>
           </with>
        </visibleWhen>
     </command>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

The above is from the CVS plugin

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the ideal solution but it worked, it makes the popup menu visible when I press right-click on a resource in the **Project Explorer** and in the **Editor** if it's associated to a resource in the Project Explorer.

This is not perfect since it's still being displayed in non Text Editor editors/views, but I can ignore the action on those cases. If someone has some suggestion to improve this please comment.

```html
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
    <definition id="com.example.definitions.resourceDefinition">
       <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource"/>
    </definition>
</extension>
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
        <command commandId="com.example.commands.myCommand">
            <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
                <or>
                    <with variable="activeEditorInput">
                        <reference definitionId="com.example.definitions.resourceDefinition"/>
                    </with>
                    <iterate>
                        <reference definitionId="com.example.definitions.resourceDefinition"/>
                    </iterate>
                </or>
            </visibleWhen>
        </command>
    <menuContribution>
</extension>
```